# preg_match is not working properly

Tags: php, regex

I have string that am checking to see if it contains valid characters.

**This is the code**

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9/-.,; ]+$/', $string)
```

**When I remove "/" it works**

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9/-.,; ]+$/', $string)
```

What can be the issue here?

Comment: You have to escape it!

Comment: And whenever something doesn't work: enable `error_reporting`, then google the error message.